# Jquery event overriding

Tags: jquery

I want to over ride an event through delegate
I am adding a delegate on table row.
I also have a button in one of the cell of the row.
Now when I click on button the button click event fires, but the row click event also fires
I don't want row click to fire when button is clicked.
[Link for my query][1]

```
$(function(){
    $("body").delegate("table tr","click",function(evt){
        alert("row clicked");
    });

    $("body").delegate("table tr input[type=button]","click",function(evt){
        alert("button clicked");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jjMVU/

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `delegate` has be deprecated in favour of `on`. Secondly, you need to stop propagation of the event. Try this:

```
$("body").on('click', "table tr input[type=button]", function(evt){ 
    evt.stopPropagation();
    alert("button clicked");
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jjMVU/3/)

Comment: row click event is not firing now
i also want row click event to fire when button is not clicked

Comment: @Swapy don't forget you need to swap over the order of parameters when using on, it's `on(event, selector, handler);`. I updated my fiddle with a full example.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of event bubbling. in order to prevent this from happening you have to use  `evt.stopPropagation()` in your button click.

So your second event handler should look like this

```
$("body").delegate("table tr input[type=button]","click",function(evt){
    evt.stopPropagation();
   alert("button clicked");
});
```